# How to save data in different variables retrieved from json

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to get data in html page from mongoDB using nodejs
I have a player collection in mongo db
     player collection:[{
     id=value,
     name=value,
     score=value,
     rank=value
     }]
I am trying to get data from nodejs file named players.js file

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({ url: "",
            context: document.div,
            success: function(){
             player[]= $(".player").load("/players")

            }});
    });
```

I am getting data in this format :

```
      [
  {
    "_id": "54c600a66770e4ea42e6f324",
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Dipesh",
    "rank": 2,
    "score": 2000,
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "54c600cb6770e4ea42e6f325",
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Aakanksha",
    "rank": 3,
    "score": 3920,
     "__v": 0
 }
```

when I saved it it variable and try to print the value of that variable using
        Document.write(varname);
It is showing me :

```
    [object Object]
```

I want data in following manner:

```
      player.name=value,
      player.score=value
```

like different values in different variables.

Please help me out as I am new with this things.
Thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var obj = [{"_id":"54c600a66770e4ea42e6f324","id":1,"name":"Dipesh","rank":2,"score":2000,"__v":0},{"_id":"54c600cb6770e4ea42e6f325","id":2,"name":"Aakanksha","rank":3,"score":3920,"__v":0}];

var temp = [];
$.each(obj,function(i,val){
    player = {};
    player.name =val.name;
    player.score = val.score;
    temp.push(player);
});
alert(JSON.stringify(temp));
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hxtzn7q3/1/)**

Comment: my json variable does not have static values stored in array. Its a player.js model file in which I am calling my data from mongoDB.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var players = [{
  "_id": "54c600a66770e4ea42e6f324",
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Dipesh",
  "rank": 2,
  "score": 2000,
  "__v": 0
}, {
  "_id": "54c600cb6770e4ea42e6f325",
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Aakanksha",
  "rank": 3,
  "score": 3920,
  "__v": 0
}];

for (var i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
  document.write(players[i].name);
}
```

Comment: When I click on `Run code snippet` then it will give `500 - Internal server error.`

Comment: @Sadikhasan: Not sure might be Stackoverflow issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Use Below Code**

`player[]` is an array that's why you have to use like below.

```
var name = player[0].name;
var score =player[0].score;
```

- For getting all elements you can use below code.

  ```
  var nameI;
  var scoreI;
  for(var i=0;i<player.length;i++){
     nameI= player[i].name;
     nameI=player[i].score; 
     ...
     ...
     ...
    // you can get all the properties for your object
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Well what you have done is you have stored the json array in a `player` variable. I am assuming that your player variable looks like :

```
var player= [
  {
    "_id": "54c600a66770e4ea42e6f324",
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Dipesh",
    "rank": 2,
    "score": 2000,
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "54c600cb6770e4ea42e6f325",
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Aakanksha",
    "rank": 3,
    "score": 3920,
     "__v": 0
 }
```

If you want to print json object then you can use `JSON.stringify()` function. This will stringify your object.

or

If you want to assign it to any variable, for that you have to loop through this object useing `$.each()` function.

Eg.

```
$.each(player,function(index,item){
  var name=item.name;
  var rank=item.rank;
  and so on...
});
```

Comment: for your help. But I dont have static data in my player[]. Its coming from mongo db. I tried your code but is not working. Should i need to make any change in my AJAX function?

Comment: Well geek..i have shown you the way how you can accomplish your goal. You  have to make changes in that code, i don't know what kind of data your server is responding you. You have to debug and customize your code.